# Using the definition of the derivative to prove a constant function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am presented with the following task:

"Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $I$. All we know about $f$ is that there is a constant $K$ such that

$$|f(a) - f(b)| \leq K|a-b|^2$$
for all $a, b \in I$. Show that $f$ is constant on $I.$ (Hint: calculate the derivative using the definition of the derivative first.)"

I am utterly confused. The Mean-Value Theorem crosses my mind while looking at the equation. I believe that I am supposed to somehow prove that $f(a) - f(b) = 0$ for all $a, b$, thus proving that the function is constant on $I$, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to make any progress in that direction.

Comment: The idea is to show $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ using the given inequality.

Comment: Is there a two as exponent of $\;|x-y|\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes.

Comment: Just a question - how is $x^2$ not a counter example to the statement in the interval [0,1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\;a,x\in I\;$ , so we're given :

$$-K|x-a|\le\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\le K|x-a|$$

pass now to the limit of the above when $\;x\to a\;$ and use the squeeze theorem. You get the middle term's limit exists **and** equals zero, and since that term's limit defines $\;f'(a)\;$ you've proved both that the derivative at $\;a\;$ exists and equals zero...

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $$0\leqslant \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right| \leqslant K|x-a|$$
and
$$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Comment: And what if $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: The OP is giving a hint mentioning the derivative of the function, which seems to point towards the possibility the OP forgot to write down this property

Comment: If that limit exists then $f$ **is** differentiable.

Comment: This works, but you have to show that $f$ is differentiable first.

Comment: This *shows* that $f$ is differentiable. :-)

Comment: @njguliyev Exactly. Some people here haven’t realized that.

Comment: Yes, I was one of them.

Comment: Thus, I can use the fact that $f'(a)$ is defined and the squeeze theorem to show that $f'(a) = 0$?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Actually, the squeeze theorem shows $f’(a)$ is defined and $f’(a)=0$. Notice the order of the arguments.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Thanks for the help, I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for example that $0\in I$ and $1\in I$.

Then

$$
|f(1)-f(0)|=\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k+1}{n})-f(\frac{k}{n})\bigg|
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \big|f(\frac{k+1}{n})-f(\frac{k}{n})\big|
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} K\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{K}{n}
$$

Since this holds for any $n$, we deduce $f(1)=f(0)$.
You can do this for any pair other than $(0,1)$.