# Real Analysis constant function

Tags: real-analysis, constants

Suppose that $f:(a,b) \to \Bbb R$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)|=M|x-y|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 1$, some $M \geq 0$, an all $(x,y)$ in $(a,b)$. Prove $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this....Full proof would be exceedingly helpful.

Comment: This question was asked recently.

Comment: Be careful. You seem to be using $a$ to mean two (possibly different) things.

Comment: Hints would be more helpful than a full proof in the long run...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507788/using-the-definition-of-the-derivative-to-prove-a-constant-function

Answer (score 2):

see that $\frac{\mid f(x) - f(y) \mid}{\mid x - y \mid} = M \mid x -y \mid ^ {a-1}$ . now use the definition of derivative to show f has derivative zero.

Comment: You should be more careful. The derivative does not necessarily exist (at every point, though it does almost everywhere since the function is absolutely continuous...)

Comment: @nayrb, the derivative exists and is equal to zero at *all* points, because $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Of course. Duh! Thanks!